# change of study plans within ABET accreditation

Tags: accreditation

Currently, I am working in a CS program that has decided to follow the ABET accreditation. The problem is that we are about to implement a new study plan for the next year, which is more suited to the outcomes that ABET asks for an accreditation in CS, because the current one has some drawbacks. The question that I have is which study plan should we present to ABET, the current one and state that the new one should be enclosed into our continuous improvement plan? What about the graduates that we have with the old study plan, should we assess them or wait until we have graduates with the new study plan?
Any help?

Comment: You should be honest. Present both plans, old and new. Better yet, why not ask ABET?

Comment: @JeffE we strive for honesty, the problem is that ABET asks for outcomes related to graduate students, I know a university that was dealing with the same problem and they present both plans, but they do not want to disclosure the details

Answer (score 1):

The best answer that can be given here, as JeffE suggests, is to ask ABET. I have had good a good experience with getting clarity regarding questions that are specific to my program's situation.

Comment: Following the comment in the OP's question, this answer provide a reasonable course of action.